# Loop through n pages inside a for loop - R

Tags: r, loops, while-loop

I'm attempting to create a script that will pull in all reviews on a given podcast in the Apple store by using the itunesr R package. I am struggling with some conditions that will make the process replicable.

```
library(itunesr)
```

I am using the getReviews() function, which requires a podcast ID, an Apple store country code, and a page number. For example:

```
pod_id <- 479679002
reviews <- getReviews(pod_id,'us',1) #returns first page of reviews in the US store.
reviews$country <- "us" #add country variable
```

I have a dataset of Apple store codes, and from that have created a for loop that will get the first page of reviews for each country store and add those to the reviews data frame.

```
code <- c("ca", "gb", "us")
country <- c("Canada", "UK", "USA")
stores <- as.data.frame(cbind(code, country))

for (i in 1:nrow(stores)) {
  try({
    x <- stores$code[[i]]
    reviews_test <- getReviews(pod_id, x ,1) 
    reviews_test$country <- x
    reviews <- rbind(reviews, reviews_test)
  }, silent = T)
}
#Remove duplicates
reviews <- reviews[!duplicated(reviews$Review), ]
```

If the number of reviews returned on a given page = 49 then there are more pages of reviews for that country. If the number of reviews returned <= 48 then there are no more reviews for that country.

I would like to add further conditions to the for loop that will move the script on to pages 2:n of reviews, for each store in the loop, as long as the number of reviews returned on each page = 49.

From the example above, there are only 8 reviews from the Canadian store, but there are 49 from the US and UK stores.

```
reviews %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  count()
```

```
country     n
  <chr>   <int>
1 ca          8
2 gb         49
3 us         49
```

What I'm trying to create would loop through page 2 of the gb and us stores, and continue looping through n pages until the number of reviews on page n were <= 48 - meaning there were no further pages.

I'm assuming I will need some sort of while/loop condition, but I'm afraid this is where I've reached the extent of my capabilities. Hope you can help.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(stores)) {
  try({
    x <- stores$code[[i]]
    reviews_loop <- getReviews(pod_id, x ,1) 
    reviews_loop$country <- x
    reviews <- rbind(reviews, reviews_test)
    if (nrow(reviews > 48)) {
      #return page 2 for that country
      #add to reviews data frame
      #repeat for 3:n pages while reviews > 48
      #otherwise, return to the start of loop and get info for next country
    };
  }, silent = T)
}
```

EDIT: Based on the the suggestion below, I tried the following but it did not work.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(stores)) {
  try({
    x <- stores$code[[i]]
    reviews_loop <- getReviews(SJ, x, 1) 
    reviews_loop$country <- x
    reviews <- rbind(reviews, reviews_test)
    if (nrow(reviews_loop > 48)) {
      for (j in 2:num_pages) {
        x <- stores$code[[i]]
        reviews_loop_new <- getReviews(pod_id, x, j) 
        reviews_loop_new$country <- x
        reviews <- rbind(reviews, reviews_loop_new)
      }
    };
  }, silent = T)
}
```

FURTHER EDIT:

Tried the solution below and ended up stuck in an endless loop. I think this is because when there are no reviews present (either on page 1 for a new country code, or on page n+1 for a country with 49 responses on pages 1:n, the response is as follows:

```
Error in names(reviews) <- c("Title", "Author_URL", "Author_Name", "App_Version",  : 
  attempt to set an attribute on NULL
```

The loop, then, needs some way of dealing with the error above. Based on the suggestion below, something like this seems closer to what I need.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(stores)) {
  try({
    page = 1
    x <- stores$code[[i]]
    reviews_test <- getReviews(pod_id, x, page) 
    reviews_test$country <- x
    reviews <- rbind(reviews, reviews_test)
    ### BREAK HERE IF REVIEWS TEST RETURNS THE ERROR ?? ##
    if (nrow(reviews_test == 49))
      repeat {
        try({
          Sys.sleep(5) ## TOO MANY CALLS = HTTP 400
          page = page + 1
          reviews_test <- getReviews(pod_id, x , page) 
          ### BREAK HERE IF REVIEWS TEST RETURNS THE ERROR ##
          reviews_test$country <- x
          reviews <- rbind(reviews, reviews_test)
          if (nrow(reviews_test < 49)) ##BREAK HERE IF REVIEWS < 49, MOVE ON TO NEXT COUNTRY CODE
        }, silent = T)
      }
    }, silent = T)
}
```

## SOLUTION

Thanks to the answer below, I now have a solution.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(stores)) {
  try({
    page = 1
    x <- stores$code[[i]]
    reviews_test <- getReviews(pod_id, x, page) 
    reviews_test$country <- x
    reviews <- rbind(reviews, reviews_test)
    if (nrow(reviews_test) == 49)
      repeat {
        try({
          Sys.sleep(5)
          page = page + 1
          reviews_test <- getReviews(SJ, x , page) 
          reviews_test$country <- x
          reviews <- rbind(reviews, reviews_test)
          if (nrow(reviews_test) < 49) break
        })#, silent = T)
      }
  }, silent = T)
}

#Then run the following line to remove the duplicated records from the original reviews data frame.

reviews <- reviews[!duplicated(reviews$Review), ]
```

Comment: Use a double loop... start another one after your if... `for (j in 2:num_pages) {`

Comment: Thanks for the response, @cory. I'm not able to make that work, I'm afraid.

Comment: It doesn't look like you've defined `num_pages`. Also, you've defined `x` in the outer loop, you don't have to redefine it in the inner loop

Comment: I think that defining num_pages is where I'm getting confused. I may have been unclear in my outline, but that number is unknown. I need the loop to continue only if the previous page has 49 rows. (Thanks for your help, by the way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just repeat every step of your loop until the number of reviews < 49:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(stores)) {
  page = 1
  x <- stores$code[[i]]
  repeat {
    try({
      reviews_test <- getReviews(pod_id, x , page) 
      reviews_test$country <- x
      reviews <- rbind(reviews, reviews_test)
      if (nrow(reviews_test) < 49) break
      page = page + 1
    }, silent = T)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks MarkusN - I tried this and it became an endless loop. See my edit above as to why I think that was. Thanks for your help. I feel as though I'm edging towards a solution.

Comment: There was an paranthesis missplaced in my first answer, I corrected it should be: (nrow(reviews_test) < 49)

Comment: That's great - thank you. It now works. I'll post the full solution in an edit above.